# OptaPlanner on Solaris is slower 5 times than on Linux os

Tags: java, linux, performance, solaris, optaplanner

I have been running OptaPlanner application on Linux servers which takes total 10 minutes.
However, when I move it to run on Solaris server the total processing time become more than 50 minutes.
And the Solaris(SPARC-T5) has more CPUs and memory than Linux(Intel).

So, I am wondering is there any settings to be done to use OptaPlanner on Solaris os?
What can be the possible reasons for this issue?

Thanks in advance for your time and answers.

Comment: What was the termination configuration? Did both had a termination configuration of the same scoreAttained? (otherwise it might not be a fair comparison)

Comment: What's the environmentMode in the solver config? The default is REPRODUCIBLE, which is a fair comparison.

Comment: 1.) This is my termination config. and both have same config. 
<termination> <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
<secondsSpentLimit>7200</secondsSpentLimit>
<bestScoreLimit>0hard/-999999soft</bestScoreLimit>
</termination>

2.) I do not define environmentMode. So I suppose it is using default one.

Comment: Agreed that both 1) and 2) are fair. The benchmark reports will be interesting.

Comment: yeah, I will try to get the reports.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting observation - I 'd like to understand what happens there too.

Create [a benchmark config](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpcPEieU3Cg) for your use case (if you haven't already), run it on both machines and share both benchmark html reports here. I'll diagnose them.

Typical causes can be: JDK version differences, JVM `-server` mode, undetermined termination config (unimprovedTimeLimit), ...
But none of that explains a *5x* difference.